# Is there any way to get the resolution of a video with Xuggler?

Tags: java, video, resolution, xuggler

I'm developing a project that it's essentially a video uploader and I want to know if is there any way to get the resolution of the uploaded video using Xuggler libraries in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the class [`IStreamCoder`](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IStreamCoder.html) there are `getHeight` and `getWidth` methods.

So you should just use these methods, [this sample](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayVideo.java) should show you how to do it.

I extracted you what should be important.

```
// Create a Xuggler container object
IContainer container = IContainer.make();

// Open up the container
if (container.open("/path/to/video.avi", IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);

// query how many streams the call to open found
int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

// and iterate through the streams to find the first video stream
int videoStreamId = -1;
IStreamCoder videoCoder = null;
for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) {
  // Find the stream object
  IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
  // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
  IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

  if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    videoStreamId = i;
    videoCoder = coder;
    break;
  }
}
if (videoStreamId == -1)
  throw new RuntimeException("could not find video stream in container: "
      +filename);

/*
 * Now we have found the video stream in this file. 
 * Let's open up our decoder so it can do work.
 */
if (videoCoder.open() < 0)
  throw new RuntimeException("could not open video decoder for container: "
      + filename);

// here you have what you need
int height = videoCoder.getHeight();
int width = videoCoder.getWidth();
```